# How to deal with bounty questions that belong to another community

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, bounty, migration

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761768/wifi-wpa2-are-spoofed-macs-rejected) is related to Server Fault, not to Stackoverflow, but bounty questions can't be closed. What should I do?

I thought of raising a flag for moderator intervention, but I don't really know how to deal with these kind of situations.

Comment: Flagging it for mod attention is an option. The question should be migrated.

Comment: It is actually more of a Network Engineering question, and the user has already [re-posted there](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25966/wifi-wpa2-are-spoofed-macs-rejected). I've deleted the post on SO.